# Is $A_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$ isomorphic to $S_3 \times S_3$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

> Ιs $A_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$ isomorphic to $S_3 \times S_3$?

I am trying to find an element of $S_3 \times S_3$ which has an order, let's say  $a$, and $A_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$ has no element of such order.

Comment: You could count the elements of order $3$.

Comment: Both groups have elements of orders $1$, $2$, $3$ and $6$.

Comment: Can $S_3\times S_3$ have a normal subgroup isomorphic to $A_4$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In $S_3\times S_3$ there are

1. $1$ element of order $1$
2. $\color{red}{15}$ elements of order $2$, $(\tau_1,e),(e,\tau_2),(\tau_1,\tau_2)$
3. $8$ elements of order $3$
4. $12$ elements of order $6$

while in $A_4\times\mathbb{Z}_3$ there are

1. $1$ element of order $1$
2. $\color{red}{3}$ elements of order $2$, $(\tau_1 \tau_2,e)$
3. $26$ elements of order $3$
4. $6$ elements of order $6$

so the easiest way to state $S_3\times S_3 \not\simeq A_4\times\mathbb{Z}_3$ is probably to compare the *number* of involutions (elements with order $2$) in both groups. Or wonder about the largest abelian subgroups, which in the former case are isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_3\times\mathbb{Z}_3$ and in the latter case are isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_3$.

Comment: $A_4$ contains only 3 elements of order two. I actually found 3 elements of order two, 26 of order three, and 6 of order six in $A_4\times\mathbb{Z}_3$.

Comment: @user26857: you're right, answer fixed.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the following useful facts.

- Given $A$ and $B$ groups, $Z(A \times B) = Z(A) \times Z(B)$.
- $Z(S_n)=\lbrace id \rbrace$ for all $n \geq 3$.